# Any way in C to request a particular file descriptor

Tags: c, file, io

The C `open()` function (in `fcntl.h`) returns an `int` as a file descriptor.  It lets you know the value of the file descriptor, but it gives you no *control over* the value.  Is there some way in C to set the value of a file descriptor, not just get it from the `open()` function?  I need something kind of like the FORTRAN `open()` statement, where the value of the file descriptor is supplied as an input.  I need this because in the system I am working on, there are a few "magic" values of file descriptors that I need to avoid.

Comment: `dup` and `dup2` give you some control over this.  So while you can't prevent `open` from giving you one of those "magic" values, you could write code that detects the case, then use `dup` or `dup2` to clone the descriptor to a hopefully better value, then close the original.

Comment: Might be stupid, but what about opening and closing the file repeatedly until your file descriptor doesn't equal one of the magic values? I.e. `while (1) { ptr = fopen("file.file"); if ptr != magic; break; else fclose(ptr); }`

Comment: @JacobFaib   That's what I said!  My boss doesn't like the idea.  :-)

Comment: You may want to introduce your boss to [Occams razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)

Comment: @JacobFaib In a single-threaded process you'd just get the same value over and over.  [`open()` returns the lowest available file descriptor value](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14)

Comment: In that case, don't close the other pointers until you've found a non-magic value? Or would this just return the same already-open file descriptor over and over again.

Comment: *there are a few "magic" values of file descriptors that I need to avoid.*  Who hardcoded file descriptor values?  That's a huge red flag to me.  You can't prevent `open()` from using one of those "magic" values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle   Wasn't my idea!  I just have to live with it.

Comment: There's no way to "live with it".  If `MAGIC_FILE_DESCRIPTOR_VALUE` is the lowest available value, the next `open()`/`creat()`/`fopen()`/`socket()`/`accept()`/`dup()`/whatever call that returns a file descriptor **will use that value**.  And you can't stop it because it happens inside the kernel.

Comment: @AndrewHenle "returns a file descriptor will use that value." Not if you delay calling `fclose()`. Calling `fopen()` on the same file repeatedly without calling `fclose()` will return different file descriptors. Although this is [*A Bad Thing* (TM)](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO24-C.+Do+not+open+a+file+that+is+already+open)

Comment: @JacobFaib At best, that's just a path to race conditions and Heisenbugs.  And you have to deal with not just `open()` but `dup()`, `pipe()`, `socket()`, `accept()`, `socketpair()`, `creat()` and a slew of others.  How are you going to handle `fopen()`?  `tmpfile()`?  `dup2()` (good luck with that one...)  Do you even know if `opendir()` uses a file descriptor internally?   How about functions like `ftw()`/`nftw()`?  What happens when you call `gethostbyname()`?  Did you even think about `openat()`? Nevermind C++ streams. "A Bad Thing (TM)" is a serious understatement. This is intractable.

Comment: "there are a few "magic" values of file descriptors" => Such a beautiful example of an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) gone too far! There should be Darwin Awards for those.